# using the range function and vlookup for a user defined function on Excel

Tags: vba, range, user-defined-functions, vlookup

Can someone please explain why the first (IncomeTax) of these 3 UDFs is able to work perfectly, but the second one (MedicareLevy) comes up with #REF! and the third (MedicareSC) one comes up with #VALUE?
The MedicareLevy one actually worked fine as well until I created the MedicareSC one, but now even when I remove the MedicareSC I can't seem to get it to work again.
I have tried replacing some of the ranges or variables from the IncomeTax function to see if it works, but yea...

```
Function IncomeTax(income As Double) As Double
 Rng = Range("taxrates")
 Base = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(income, Rng, 2)
 minbrac = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(income, Rng, 1)
 taxRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(income, Rng, 3)
 IncomeTax = Base + (income - minbrac) * taxRate
End Function


Function MedicareLevy(income As Double) As Double
 ExemptionLimit = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(income, Range("medicarelevy"), 2)
 LevyRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(income, Range("medicarelevy"), 3)
 MedicareLevy = (income - ExemptionLimit) * LevyRate
End Function

Function MedicareSC(income As Double, insurance As String) As Double
 Rng = Range("medicaresurcharge")
 SCRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(income, Rng, 2)
If insurance = "yes" Then
    MedicareSC = 0
ElseIf insurance = "no" Then
MedicareSC = income * SCRate
End If
End Function
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  What is `Range("medicarelevy")`?  One thing I see you're missing is the `Set` statement in `Rng = Range("medicaresurcharge")`. This would have been more obvious if you had declared your variables & objects (for example `Dim Rng as Range`), which would have been "mandatory" if you had the line `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module....  I'd suggest you start with that and if you're still having trouble after all of your variables and objects are declared, [edit] your question with the updated code and problem details.  (Also see **[mcve]**)

Comment: These are all using the currently activesheet as you don't fully qualify the ranges with their parent sheets.

Comment: SCRate  should be declared as variant and then you shouldn't handle the case of not found and  insurance As String could be a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I fixed it now. I still don't understand why my first one was able to work fine. But, I guess what matters is that it worked! In case anyone ever has a similar problem though, I also had to change the UDF name so that it wasn't the same as a defined range. I also didn't have to change the insurance variable to a boolean. Although I would actually prefer that, it's just that the variable is meant for a predefined cell that is meant to answer a yes or no question and I can't seem to find the code to make yes=true and no=false unfortunately